# How to create a Cordova Application that accepts input from the user and gives the same content when click the button?

Tags: cordova, cordova-ios

I am new to Cordova programming. I want to create a Cordova Application that accepts input from the user and creates a new paragraph on the page containing the text input by the user each time the user clicks the submit button. With my code I can only input something but get no output.

Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *; img-src 'self' data: content:;">
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
            <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
                    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
                    <title>Hello World</title>
                    </head>

<body>
    <input type="text" id="myText"=></input>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Add</button>

    <p id="demo"></p>

    <script type="test/javascrpt">
        function myFunction() {
            var myText = document.getElementById("myText").value;
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myTest;
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You just have small typos in your code.

```
function myFunction() {
  var myText = document.getElementById("myText").value;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myText; // You had myTest
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myText"></input>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Add</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
  function myFunction() {
    var myText = document.getElementById("myText").value;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myText;
  }
</script>
```